# Wordpress export function, ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE. I've raised execution times and memory limits to absurdly high values, and no change

Tags: wordpress

I can not find a solution to this, but I see lots of threads online where people ask this question and on wordpress.com and they just take care of it without providing a solution.

I have Cpanel and WHM access, the site is self hosted. I can make any change I need to make, but I can't figure out what is causing the issue.

I can export everything but (Variaciones - site is in spanish, not sure if it is variable, variations, etc).

I currently have php memory at a GB, execution at 1500 seconds.

What could cause this to happen? If I select "export all content", it fails at 90 seconds. If I select just "variaciones", it fails at 20.

Any advice that could get me on the right track would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And what are you using to export, exactly?

Comment: The built in export function. I considered trying a plugin, but I'd like to understand what server setting I have that is causing this.